# How to freeze revision for a file in SVN

Tags: svn

I have a a project file under configuration control that always when I open the project, the IDE changes it, but with irrelevant changes, which I do not desire to make commit.

So I want to "freeze" this file, so it continues under version control, but the new changes are ignored by `svn st` command (ok, you could say for me just don't commit! But that's just what I've been doing, so I want a better solution). Maybe is there a property that I could make this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be under version control, there is, probably, no way to ignore changes in it.

If it doesn't have to be under version control just add it to SVN ignored files.

However -- if the change is irrelevant, maybe you can prevent this file from change?

My IDE saves some internal version info into source files, so we wrote a small add-in to revert these changes on IDE exit -- this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This file just **must not to be under version control**, if you can't see reasons to store (and propagade) changes.

In order to answer - you can't freeze versioned file. Period

Comment: That's the point. The file MUST be under version control, and specifically that version. And if I include new files to the project, this new version shall be under version control too, but other changes are useless.